# Android transition animation onBackPressed() image vanishes (failed to release buffer)

Tags: java, android

Not sure how or why this started happening, as it used to work

I have an image view I run a transition animation on (still works)

```
Intent i = new Intent(thisActivity, NewActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
View imageContainer = findViewById(R.id.image_container);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(thisActivity, imageContainer, "logo_transition");
startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

When I called super.onBackPressed() in the NewActivity it used to reverse the transition and look very nice. Now, the image just vanishes and this appears in logcat

```
BufferItemConsumer: [unnamed-6194-5] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
```

styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@transition/change_image_transform</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@transition/change_image_transform</item>
```

transition/change_image_transform.xml

```
<transitionSet
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="375"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:transitionOrdering="together"
    android:startDelay="50">
    <changeClipBounds/>
    <changeTransform/>
    <changeBounds/>
</transitionSet>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/company_logo"
    android:id="@+id/image_container"
    android:transitionName="logo_transition"/>
```

NewActivity.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="500dp"
    android:maxHeight="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/company_logo"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:transitionName="logo_transition"
    android:id="@+id/logo_container"/>
```